# how to read from first 1 to 500 character from file in phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova

I have a file I want to read first 500 character  from a file in phonegap .I read whole file like that But I need to read only first 500 character .

```
function readRtfFile2(){


 try {
           window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
               function(fileSystem) {
                   fileSystem.root.getDirectory("casepad_files", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(directoryEntry) {

                       console.log("log folder is created");
                       directoryEntry.getFile("backup.json", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(fileEntry) {
                                              fileEntry.file(function(file){
                   var reader = new FileReader();
                   reader.onloadend = function(evt){
                    //alert(evt.target.result);
                     //$('#realTimeContents').val(evt.target.result);
                       myScroll.refresh();
//setInterval(function(){

//nativePluginResultHandler(evt.target.result);},3000);

                   //  $("#RLTRightDiv").html(evt.target.result);
                 $("#scroller").html(evt.target.result);
                       myScroll.refresh();
                    var scrollerDivHeight=  $('#scroller').height();
                     var wrapperDivHeight=  $('#wrapper').height();
                     //alert(scrollerDivHeight);
                    // alert(wrapperDivHeight);
                        if(scrollerDivHeight<=1130){
                         myScroll.disable()
                      }
                   };
                   reader.readAsText(file);                        
                   },fail);

                       }, fail);
                   }, fail);
               },
               fail);
       }
       catch(e) {
           fail(e+"fail");
       }




}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the first n characters of a string, you would use `substr(0, n)` where n is the number of characters you want. So in your case, you would use:

```
$("#scroller").html(evt.target.result.substr(0,500));
```